# Can greatest integer function under variable be added?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

**[.] Represents greatest integer function**

```
                     [x]+[2x]+[3x]+[4x]+.....[nx]=[n(n+1)/2]
```

So,
If we are given variable X in the Greatest integer, can we just add all of em ?

Comment: In general. $[x]+[y]\ne [x+y]$. -- Your longer equality holds only when $1\le x<1+\frac1n$

Comment: Appreciate your help! With the details :)